# Is it possible to use AWS CodeCommit as a backend git server for GitLab?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I have a [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) deployment which is great since it provides a great GUI, however it's not nearly as scalable or persistent as something like [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/).

Is it possible to use CodeCommit or some other Git Server as a backend for GitLab?

Comment: No, you can't use CodeCommit as a "backend" for GitLab. You can, however, deploy GitLab on EC2 using the `gitlab-aws-image` AMI as mentioned [here](https://about.gitlab.com/aws/). There is also more information on GitLab HA [here](https://about.gitlab.com/high-availability/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CodeCommit as the source repository for GitLab.  You can however mirror it for various good reasons like disaster recovery or backup.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html